# Error reading json on a compiled LibGDX java game

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jar, libgdx

I've made a little java game using libgdx, and everything works perfectly fine, until i try to execute the **compiled .jar**.

The error that the jar returns look like this (I've printed the e.getMessage() and the stackTrace on a text file):

```
    Error reading file: ui/menuSkin.json

 --> com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:96)
 --> com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:81)
 --> com.castell.randomcastle.screens.BasicsScreen.show(BasicsScreen.java:105)
 --> com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
 --> com.castell.randomcastle.RandomCastleMain.create(RandomCastleMain.java:12)
 --> com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:137)
 --> com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:115)
```

And the line which launches the error looks like this:

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/menuSkin.json"), new TextureAtlas("ui/atlas.pack"));
```

It seems that the file can be found (and I have other referenced files with "Gdx.files.internal" that works fine before that line), but there's an error on reading it.

**EDIT:** After some more testing I found out that the error was actually that the file could not be found, as stuntmania told me in the comments below.

The strange thing about this, is that **when I try to execute the progrem via eclipse, with the exact same json, it works perfectly fine**. The error only comes when I execute the compiled jar.

The compiled jar has no warnings, and I compiled it by right-clicking on the "desktop" project, Export -> Runnable jar file, and tried both "extract required libraries" and "package required libraries"

I've googled about it and I could not find anything useful or similar to what's happening here, hope that you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: libgdx can't find the actual file itself. Make sure you have exported the .json file in you .jar.

Comment: Yes, the json is in the jar, and a couple of months ago I compiled an earlier version and it worked correctly, and the json is called the same exact way. The only thing that changes from that earlier version that works from this one, is the json itself, and that in the new one is initialised from a parent class. Thanks.

Comment: @stuntmania you are right, the problem is that the file can't be found, thanks. I edited the question. But still, I can't find out how to make it work. The path of the json file is "assets/ui/menuSkin.json", and the json is in the jar file.

Comment: I had this error as well earlier in my game. Instead of using Gdx.files.internal(), I am using Gdx.files.classpath(). Classpath refers to the project itself, so you will have to type in:
Gdx.files.classpath("assets/ui/menuSkin.json");. That should solve the problem. If it doesn't, comment back.

Comment: Thanks again @stuntmania, I tried it and it still doesn't work. This is what I have in the generated .jar: [link](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img62/8246/k3ho.png). I tried Gdx.files.classpath("assets/ui/menuSkin.json"), Gdx.files.classpath("ui/menuSkin.json"), Gdx.files.classpath("./ui/menuSkin.json") and none of them worked

Comment: Do you use the old libgdx project structure or the new one with gradle? If you have a `build.gradle` file, run `gradle dist` and there should be a jar file in `project/desktop/build/libs` if the build succeeded.

Comment: Hello @dermetfan and thanks for answering. I'm using the old libgdx project structure, I don't have anything like `buld.gradle`

Comment: Castell, I can't really see from the picture, is there any src package / folder somewhere? @dermetfan we meet again! >:)

Comment: I haven't got any repository or something. @dermetfan asked me the same so I uploaded the whole project in my mega account, you can download it [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!uRIkhTID!sM-04m_FYy5yc9Bm0wmn9PWQuhiI0zDRXL4FZ6uq3Qo). If you compile and execute a jar and it crashes, there should appear an error log in your Documents folder, inside a folder named "CastleMadness". Thank you all guys :)